# Api Gateway Authorizer Authorization Caching Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

After creating and using an Authorizer in Api Gateway, there is an option to enable Authorization Caching, with a variable TTL(seconds) settings.

[image: Edit Authorzizer]

What is the pricing involved with this authorization caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own experience, there is no charge associated to this auth caching. You are actually saving money when you enable auth* caching since Lambda will not be invoked

However you can get into [this nasty problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331588/aws-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-strange-showing-error) that I faced when enable that cache

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using this feature for REST API, refer to this link,:
https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/
[image]

Note that:

Caching is charged by the hour and is not eligible for the AWS Free Tier.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lambda Authorizer caching. Your screenshot belongs to caching for REST APIs, which is entirely different.